# Bogus oauth2client.tools.run() deprecation warning from GAE appcfg.py (linux, SDK 1.9.19)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm fumbling with manual GAE uploads since pycharm can't handle yet properly uploads of multi-module apps.
At some point I've seen this message:

```
####################################################
OAuth2 is now the recommended authentication method.
Use the --oauth2 flag to enable.
####################################################
```

Right, I read about this, so I started using the **--oauth2** flag. To my surprise I now see a deprecation warning at every **appcfg.py** invocation:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py --oauth2 update_indexes a_module_dir -A my_app_name
...
2015-04-25 19:52:17,169 WARNING old_run.py:88 This function, oauth2client.tools.run(), and the use of the gflags library are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the library. 
...
```

And the update is OK, no issue.

I noticed the warning in logs from other SO Q&As as well, even on windows, but those discussions focus on other stuff, not on this warning in particular. 
Also seen in the pycharm GAE upload logs for a single module app.

Is this warning something I should start worrying about?

Or is it just an oversight in this SDK version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO this is a valid answer, should not be just a comment...

Comment: Deleted comment and made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the warning; we (the GAE team) missed it for the 1.9.19 release but it is fixed for the 1.9.20 release (currently going through QA).

Answer (score 0):

Ignore? It completely prevents Google App Engine Launcher from deploying your site/app... Upon hitting Deploy, it directs you to accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?....blahblah, you press the accept button for your account, then it displays your local page at http://localhost:8080/?code=...(long code# here) , and that's it - no deployment.  Doesn't remember your accepting the terms of oauth, so you see that every time you attempt to deploy.  The command window outputs:

2015-05-01 14:24:29 Running command: "['C:\python27_x64\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py', '--oauth2', 'update', 'C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\Desktop - Me\mysite']"
02:24 PM Application: myappenginenamehere; version: 1
02:24 PM Host: appengine.google.com
02:24 PM 
Starting update of app: iconic-treat-728, version: 1
02:24 PM Getting current resource limits.
2015-05-01 14:24:31,996 WARNING old_run.py:88 This function, oauth2client.tools.run(), and the use of the gflags library are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the library. 
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this application with the command-line parameter

--noauth_local_webserver

Comment: What you describe might be Windows specific (I saw something along these lines in another answer).  I didn't see this on Linux,  deployment was OK. Thanks.

Comment: True, I should have mentioned this pertains to version 1.9.19 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 7 and GAE 1.9.20 and I see this same problem.
I am using the GUI App Engine Launcher and its DEPLOY button.
It is NOT fixed as reported above, at least not on Windows 7.

If it didn't take at least a half an hour to load a GAE version,
reloading an old version would be a more viable solution.

Comment: I have changed back to GAE 1.19.19, tried to deploy. same bug. Then I switched my default browser from I.E. 11 to Chrome and was able to deploy my app just fine. So The bug happens when GAE launcher tries to bring up the authentication acceptance, uses the default browser of I.E.11, and fails. I have reasons unrelated to GAE why I use IE as my default browser.